# Store data in Custom Fields or attachment in ics iCal file

Tags: calendar, icalendar

I need to give my manually built iCal file (.ics) some additional infos which I actually don't want to be visible for Calendar app users. Thus I need to be able to set them manually when creating an Event in an iOS application and (later) reading them from the Calendar events.

I was wondering whether it is possible to add custom fields / attributes to a iCal / .ics file itself (not by using a calendar application!). They shall not be displayed in a Calendar application but accessible for me as a mobile app developer to store IDs, references, anything when I read them out from a calendar on the device... Until now the only possibility seems to be storing those vales as description / notes, but I'm definitely not happy with that!
Is there any possibilltity? Neither could I achieve it by now nor did I find anything useful on the internet...

As an alternative, I was thinking about using the Attachment function of iCal, which - unfortunately - is visible for invited persons and the organizer himself and may not be editable / updated when edited...

Thanks in advance!

Below: ics example date

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//Mac OS X 10.12.2//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
DTSTART:19810329T020000
TZNAME:MESZ
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
DTSTART:19961027T030000
TZNAME:MEZ
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20170330T114118Z
UID:38F0C7FE-9711-437F-A5FE-E670E97C6766
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20170330T160000
TRANSP:OPAQUE
ATTENDEE;CN="John Doe";CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;EMAIL="john@doe.de";PAR
 TSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:john@doe.de
X-APPLE-TRAVEL-ADVISORY-BEHAVIOR:AUTOMATIC
SUMMARY:iCal Test100

CUSTOM:*** WHAT I WOULD NEED ***

DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20170330T153000
DTSTAMP:20170330T114208Z
ORGANIZER;CN="Jon Doh":mailto:Jon@Doh.de
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define your own properties and parameters.  Just make sure they start with "X-".  For example:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID;X-FOO=bar:38F0C7FE-9711-437F-A5FE-E670E97C6766
X-SUPER-SECRET:abc123
...
END:VEVENT
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, seems to work by half. If I create an iCal event on my Mac and then invite myself (another email) the X-... gets lost in some constellations. Did I put it in the wrong place (did it like you said) or is this just unavoidable?

Comment: It sounds like you want the calendar application to preserve the "X-" properties?  The calendar application will likely discard the "X-" properties, unless it knows how to process them.

Comment: @Muli, did you ever find a good solution for this? I have exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Edward No, unfortunately I did not. The solution we came up with has to parts: 
First, we stored the UUID which we needed in the end in the URL with the scheme of our app so we could open the calendar item directly inside our app.

And Second, all other data that we needed is stored in the Notes field, which is not a nice but a working solution. We added a not like 
*** DO NOT TOUCH THIS *** \n <data> **********
but of course users are able to edit it... Hope this helps anyway

Comment: Thanks! Did you consider storing it in a "X-APPLE-my-tag" property? I didn't write my code yet but was hoping that the calendar app maybe leaves any custom Apple headers intact.

Comment: @Edward So have you tried it with X-APPLE-my-tag properties? The project I'd have needed it is over but I'm still curios :)

Comment: @mmika1000 To be honest, I don't really remember. It seems I'm adding X-<MY_APP>-... tags to *some* of the events, and it looks like I'm doing some processing with it as well, but I can't find any of these X-<MY_APP>-... tags in any of my actual production calendars. ‍♂️

Comment: @Edward I tried adding a custom X property ie. "X-TYPE" in ics file but it is ignored by outlook client. For gmail it works fine. Any alternate solution in case of outlook?

Comment: If you need to store data that will not be removed by calendar software, I recommend saving the event's UID in your database and then storing the information there. The UID will never be changed by calendar software