# What is the meaning of X-LIC-LOCATION in ICS file?

Tags: icalendar

In some online icalendar examples https://github.com/collective/icalendar/blob/master/src/icalendar/tests/test_timezoned.py#L50 , I find code like:

```
        tzc = icalendar.Timezone()
        tzc.add('tzid', 'Europe/Vienna')
        tzc.add('x-lic-location', 'Europe/Vienna')
```

What is the meaning of 'x-lic-location' ? Where is it's specification?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store data in Custom Fields or attachment in ics iCal file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117843/store-data-in-custom-fields-or-attachment-in-ics-ical-file)

Comment: Thanks! That is part of the answer. The remaining part is - which calendar app uses this custom field and why.

Comment: Indications are that it is google, the reason given in this blog post is "to hint at a location with X-LIC-LOCATION" since Timezone inadequate.  http://jon.netdork.net/2008/10/11/wrapping-my-head-around-ical/.   Try creating a test event in the calendar of each application and check the resulting .ics file. More than one application may be using it.  Playing around with keywords shows nothing definitive however it does appear to be google .ics files in examples quoted.   It would be interesting to know how google uses it - under what situations would the X-LIC-LOCATION change behaviour?